# Linux Subsystem on Windows + Node.js: EINVAL error

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, pipe, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a bash script that runs a `cmd` that pipes something into the Node.js executable under Windows. Like this:

```
$ /mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /C "echo console.log('hi') | node"
```

Yes, it's ugly. But it worked perfectly until recently. I think the actual major Windows update broke the stuff, now I got the following error from Node:

```
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, uv_pipe_open
at new Socket (net.js:200:18)
at createWritableStdioStream (internal/process/stdio.js:164:16)
at process.getStdout [as stdout] (internal/process/stdio.js:14:14)
at console.js:243:38
at NativeModule.compile (bootstrap_node.js:596:7)
at Function.NativeModule.require (bootstrap_node.js:541:18)
at setupGlobalConsole (bootstrap_node.js:310:41)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:70:7)
at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Note that if I call the script from Linux without the pipe-to-node OR if I call the echo-pipe-to-node from Windows then it works. But it crashes if I want to run a cmd that pipes into Node from bash. Any ideas?

BTW this Linux Subsystem is a pretty cool stuff. :D

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the same issue, but the error message looks similar in [https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2370](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2370). Apparently there is a fix in Windows 10 build 17618.